# gcc (tdm64-1) 10.3.0 - undefined reference to `IID_IPropertySetStorage'

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, ole

I'm trying to compile a Microsoft sample code from MSDN with GCC, but the linker can't find a definition.

I'm using the compiler "[g++ (tdm64-1) 10.3.0](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/download/)".

The source code is "*WriteRead.cpp*"  from https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/stg/writeread-sample.

Into the source the compile command line suggested is "*cl /GX WriteRead.cpp*".    But as I'm trying to build with GCC, I have changed it to "g++ -m64 WriteRead.cpp -o WriteRead.exe -luser32 -lkernel32 -lOle32".

That's when I got the error:

```
C:/DESENV/TDM-GCC-64_v10.3.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\WillianBR\AppData\Local\Temp\ccJrTAQs.o:WriteRead.cpp:
(.rdata$.refptr.IID_IPropertySetStorage[.refptr.IID_IPropertySetStorage]+0x0): 
undefined reference to `IID_IPropertySetStorage'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The [StgCreateStorageEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/coml2api/nf-coml2api-stgcreatestorageex) function define this parameter as being "**REFIID riid**".

##### *[in] riid*

> A value that specifies the interface identifier (IID) of the interface pointer to return. This IID may be for the IStorage interface or the IPropertySetStorage interface.

### **Does anyone has a hint about this issue?**

Build the Microsoft sample with GCC x64.

Comment: Compiled with clang, looks ok. Do you really need gcc?